# Are tools required in practicing angular js?

Tags: angularjs

some of my angulajs examples are not working(like angular routing). I am practising them on notepad and excuting them browser.DO i need to work on tool(like eclipse or visual studio) to make them work ?

Below is my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <!-- Placeholder for views-->
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

foo.js

var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

```
demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/view1',{templateUrl: 'View1.html',controller: 'SimpleController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2',{templateUrl: 'View2.html',controller: 'SimpleController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
});
var controllers = {};
controllers.SimpleController = function($scope){
    $scope.customers = [
        {name:'John Doe',city:'Phoenix'},
        {name:'Jane Doe',city:'New York'},
        {name:'Terrence Winter',city:'Los Angeles'},
        {name:'Barack Obama',city:'Washington DC'}
    ];
    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
        $scope.customers.push(
            {
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name, 
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city
            });
    };
}
demoApp.controller(controllers);
```

View1.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3>View 1</h3>
    Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name"/>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'name'"> {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    Customer Name: <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
    <br>
    Customer City: <br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>
    <br>
    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <br>
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

View2.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>View 2</h3>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="city"/>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:'city'"> {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, you don't. Just include AngularJS files in your HTML.

Comment: Can you provide the error you get in console? So maybe we will be able to help you (about `angular-routing`?)

Comment: I am not getting any error in IE but in firefox I am able to see error like window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection

Comment: @Mistalis I have added my code. can you please let me know where I went wrong

Answer (score -1):

No you can certainly use notepad, but at a great disadvantage. You might want to try Visual Code for free or download the trial of webstorm. I use VS2015 and it does have some nice tooling: WallabyJS, Resharper, etc.. .but it is not needed. Can you post more about the problem you are having and perhaps one of us can help you with the issue..

Comment: I have added code . could you please help me in this